# How to fix: TypeError: _get_unique_zone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shortcut_id_y'?

Tags: python, arguments, position

I'm pretty new to Python and trying to make a code which can calculate the real time of locations based on longitude.

It already worked, but now, it want the parameter `self` fullfilled. I defined `self` and now THAT is solved, but now if I try to use `offset(City, self=tf)` it gives me this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Marvi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    GMTcor = time_in - offset(City, self=tf) * 60 + realTime
  File "C:\Users\Marvi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 45, in offset
    tz_target = timezone(tf.certain_timezone_at(self,lat=target['lat'], lng=target['lng']))
  File "C:\Users\Marvi\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject1\lib\site-packages\timezonefinder\timezonefinder.py", line 744, in certain_timezone_at
    timezone = self._get_unique_zone(shortcut_id_x, shortcut_id_y)
TypeError: _get_unique_zone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shortcut_id_y'
```

and i don't have any clue how to fix it... Please help me!
The whole code is down here: (it's messy, I know)

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from datetime import timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
import datetime
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

address = input("Insert place: ")
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Time Correction Calculator")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
print(location.address)

t = input("Insert time (hh:mm): ")
(h, m) = t.split(':') 
time_in = int(h) * 60 + int(m) 


date_input = input("Insert date (dd.mm.yyyy): ")

utc = pytz.utc
tf = TimezoneFinder

def offset(target, self):
    today = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_input, '%d.%m.%Y') # reading of date_in and Splitting it
    tz_target = timezone(tf.certain_timezone_at(self,lat=target['lat'], 
    lng = target['lng'])) # Searching timezone by coordinates
    today_target = tz_target.localize(today)
    today_utc = utc.localize(today)
    return (today_utc - today_target).total_seconds() / 3600 # Calculating the timezone in hours

City = dict({'lat' : location.latitude, 'lng' : location.longitude})

realTime : float = location.longitude * 4 # Longitude to minutes
realTime = round(realTime)

Correction = time_in - offset(City, self=tf) * 60 + realTime # Calculating the real time in minutes
print(str(timedelta(hours = GMTcor / 60))[:-3]) # printing the real Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit a line: 25 while searching the timezones by coordinate.

Replace the line: 25

```
tz_target = timezone(tf.certain_timezone_at(self,lat=target['lat'], lng=target['lng'])) # Searching timezone by coordinates
```

With:

```
tz_target = timezone(tf().certain_timezone_at(lat=target['lat'], lng=target['lng'])) # Searching timezone by coordinates
```

You need to call `certain_timezone_at()` using an object of `TimezoneFinder` instead of calling it from class reference.

for e.g. `tf().certain_timezone_at(lat=target['lat'], lng=target['lng'])`

Also, there is no need to pass `self` while calling the object level method. That will be passed implicitly by the python interpreter.

Have a look at this code diff.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Unfortunatly, it doesn't work. It did before exactly like that, but there was an update or smth and it broke. If I remove the self, I get this error: TypeError: certain_timezone_at() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Hey, I just edited my answer. There was some other issue as well. Please take a look at it. 
However, you need to fix the import error while using `GMTcor`. That's a different issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works! :DD